# npm This package is no longer supported

Tags: angular2, npm

Запускаю

`npm install --save crypto`

Получаю предупреждение

```
deprecated crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
```

Подскажите, что я должен сделать, чтобы работать с данным пакетом?